# Mounting an image which is connected in the cdrom of Ubuntu VM

Tags: 12.04, mount

I have an iso file connected with the cd drive of an Ubuntu VM. Now I am trying to mount it .

I have tried `mount -o loop /dev/cdrom  /mnt/cdrom`  and it mounts properly but when I try to execute any command on the extracted file it says `Mounted as readonly` .

I have tried `mount -o remount,rw /dev/cdrom /mnt/cdrom` but it says `Specify file type` .

I have tried `mount -t auto -o remount,rw -force /dev/cdrom /mnt/cdrom`  It again says `Specify a file type`

I have tried  `mount -t ext -o remount,rw -force /dev/cdrom /mnt/cdrom`  It says `Bad option`

Please let me know what I have to do to mount /dev/cdrom

Answer (score 0):

Try these commands,

```
sudo umount /dev/cdrom
sudo chmod 777 /mnt/cdrom                 # Gives Read,Write,Execute permission for all who tries to access cdrom directroy
sudo mount -o loop /path/to/iso/file/YOUR_ISO_FILE.ISO /mnt/cdrom
```

Comment: Hey Avinash, It is saying can't find `/mnt/cdrom in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab`

Answer (score 0):

When you try mount device (`/dev/cdrom`) it will act like device CDROM. Thus you will not able to remount it in read-write mode. I suggest you to mount ISO file (with option `loop`) instead then remount it in read-write mode. Or you can combine these two options:

```
sudo mount -o loop,rw /path/to/cd-image.iso /mnt/cdrom
```

However, trying this command gave me such output:

```
$ sudo mount -o loop,rw Install/ubuntu-10.04-dvd-amd64.iso  /mnt
mount: block device /home/karimov-danil/Install/ubuntu-10.04-dvd-amd64.iso is write-protected, mounting read-only
```

So, only option is left to mount/open it as archive, extract files you want to execute and execute them in filesystem mounted in read-write mode.

Comment: Hi Danatela,  I have first mounted with loop then when i tried to remount I am facing error that, `Cannot remount block device /dev/loop0 read-write, is write-protected` .

Comment: The only option you have is to copy needed files onto filesystem and execute them there.